# angular 4: routing behavior after build --prod

Tags: angular

I have an issue with routing when I build my app with ng build --prod.
The router.config doesn't register these routes only in prod environment.

error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'myvehicle'↵Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'myvehicle'

vehicle-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ConfigService } from '../../core/services/config/config.service';
import { VehicleComponent } from './vehicle.component';

const vehicleRoutes: Routes = [];

ConfigService.scope('vehicle').getConfig().map(vehicle => {
  vehicleRoutes.push({
    path: vehicle['informations']['route'],
    component: VehicleComponent,
  });
});

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(vehicleRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class VehicleRoutingModule { }

export const routedComponents = [VehicleComponent];
```

header.component.html

```
<a [routerLink]="[vehicleService.getRoute(vehicle.id)]">...
```

The routing works when I use the following code instead of the code above:

```
const vehicleRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "test-a",
    component: VehicleComponent,
  },{
    path: "test-b",
    component: VehicleComponent,
  }
];
```

I checked the path value and it's the same in the both ways as well as the console.log(vehicleRoutes) output in dev / prod environment.

ps: the path is loaded via an http request because it's based on slug set in the back office.

Comment: `<a [routerLink]="[vehicleService.getRoute(vehicle.id)]">...` - where is this `vehicleService` located? injected into `header.component`?

Comment: the VehicleService is located in the core folder and provided by the CoreModule which is imported by my AppModule, following the angular style guide rule https://angular.io/styleguide#!#04-11

After that I injected the service in my header component: constructor(public vehicleService: VehicleService) {}

Comment: ah, ok, got it, maybe create a plunker

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the base url in index.html file in **base tag**

Example :

```
<base href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/" target="_blank">
```